# Pidgin not working

Tags: 12.04, pidgin

I'm using Pidgin 2.10.3 (libpurple 2.10.3)

System-Ubuntu 12.04.3.

While starting the Pidgin, I'm getting error as

```
Server does not use any supported authentication method
```

The settings which was required are given properly(username,domain,password).

What can be the issue and how I can be able to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding the hostname in the /etc/hosts file.

[Unable to connect to Google Talk using Pidgin (SASL error)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88989/unable-to-connect-to-google-talk-using-pidgin-sasl-error)

Hope it will be useful for others.